# Is any easy way to put 'value' in single quote for select statement in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to select thousand of individual values from database.
(Note - These all values are provided by customer)

Query -

```
Select * from test_table where id in ('value-1','value-2'.......'value-1000');
```

Any easy way to create this query in oracle sql developer tool. As putting values between ['',] takes so much time.

Comment: How are the values provided? If the customer provided them in a file you could use an external table, perhaps. If not, SQL Developer's find and replace support regular expressions, which could make this quite simple.

Comment: Are values always in this same format, with a fixed prefix followed by an incrementing number?

Comment: They just randomly provide values by mail or simple text file.

Comment: My first take on this is, start loading the values into a lookup table so that you do not use them as literals in the `IN` clause. Because once you exceed `1000` values it won't work as that's the limit by Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options:

1. Use find/replace or even regex replace to generate the quoted values and then paste them.

Tip: If you're on Windows Notepad++ had very good regex support in its find/replace.

For example if each line contains a column you can quote each line and add a comma with Notepad++ by replacing `(.*)` with `'\1',` using search mode = Regular expression.

However if you have all data on one line separated by spaces you should use `([^ ]*)` as the search expression.

2. Somehow load the values into a separate table (e.g. by importing data or generating INSERT statements using find/replace or regex) and then use `SELECT ... JOIN` to list all matches.

In Notepad++, if each line contains a column, create INSERT statements byreplacing `(.*)` with `INSERT INTO tablename (colname) VALUES ('\1');` using search mode = Regular expression.

Note: The Notepad++ suggestions above assume no quotes appear in your data. If there are you need to double them first by replacing `'` with `''`.

Comment: Please tell me regexp that works in notepad++. I have values like 1111 2222 333 33 3336

Comment: Okay, I added the Notepad++ regex instructions. Enjoy ;-)